# How to centre an equation in OneNote?

Tags: microsoft-onenote, microsoft-onenote-2013

I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to centre align an equation but once the file is closed and reopened, the equation becomes left aligned automatically. How to make it centre align permanently ?

Answer (score 1):

Incredibly late to this but this bug still exists in OneNote as of 11/10/2022. Furthermore, it occurs when autosaves/cloudsaves are enabled. The only workaround I have found so far was on this [bug report](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/equation-centering-bug-in-onenote-2013/2e6cbd35-b4fb-42ec-bce3-fda0cd7ae86e) from June 2013.

The workaround from a user there was to make the equation into a numbered equation by adding #(number) to the end of your equation, then deleting the equation's number later. This technically leaves the equation as a 'numbered equation' however visually it just looks centered. E.g.

stress = force / area#1
25 = 13 + 12#2

Then just delete the numbers that appear at the side.

Comment: This was incredibly helpful! I've been wanting to number *and* center equations in OneNote for Mac for ages. I could not find the syntax for numbering equations. Also, if you leave a trailing space, i.e. `# `, then the text is centered and there's no need to delete anything. Hopefully Google puts this question higher in the search ranking.